# Escape equals sign in terraform

Tags: escaping, terraform, equals

I'm in a terraform project, have .tfvars file like this :

```
my_credentials = "secret=="
project_name = "project name"
en_name = "current_env"
```

I have a script that search from that file the line with the var requested (here i want to get my_credentials). But when I run this script I just get

`"secret"`

while i want to get

`"secret=="`

I think I have to escape the = sign, but I found no documentation about it, I tried somethings like

```
my_credentials = "secret\\=\\="
```

which returns "secret\\"

If you have an idea, I'll take it

Comment: Can you show a fully worked example of this in a [mcve] please? Ideally something as minimal as a variable and an output that outputs that variable. Doing exactly that locally doesn't drop the `=` characters when I try it.

Comment: It's a kinda complex project, but to make it simple you have a file .tfvars which stores some variables like this :
my_credentials = "secret=="
project_name = "project_name"
etc ...
and you just have a python script that read this file, find the line where you have the var searched (here my_credentials), and return the value of the var (here secret==)

Comment: You should edit your example into your question.

Comment: Can you share a minimal version of the script that is reading that tfvars file? It sounds like your issue is there rather than in Terraform.

Comment: I had the == pattern because i was encoding `secret` in base 64, and then putting it in the .tfvars, I found a workaround, I encode it after I retrieved it in my script, thx tho for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the == pattern because i was encoding secret in base 64, and then putting it in the .tfvars, I found a workaround, I encode it after I retrieved it in my script